# How to configure logstash 2.3.3 websocket

Tags: sockets, websocket, logstash

I am trying to get logstash 2.3.3 websocket input working.

Logstash: https://download.elastic.co/logstash/logstash/logstash-2.3.3.tar.gz

Websocket Input Plugin for Logstash: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-websocket.html

Websocket server: https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/releases/download/v0.2.11/websocketd-0.2.11-linux_amd64.zip

Websocket Client: Chrome Plugin "Simple Web Socket Client"

I am aware of a bug filed last year logstash 1.5.0 and the websocket input plugin. https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-websocket/issues/3 I have also received those same error messages, although I can't reproduce them anymore. The following is my current procedure and result. I am hoping that bug has since been fixed and I just can't find the correct config.

First I installed the plugin and confirmed it is listed as installed.

```
/app/bin/logstash-plugin list | grep "websocket"
```

Next, I checked that logstash was working with the following config

```
input {
  stdin { }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash-log.txt"
  }
}
```

Logstash worked.

```
/app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/logstash agent --config /app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash.conf
Hello World
```

The file logstash-log.txt contained:

```
{"message":"Hello World","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-07-05T20:04:14.850Z","host":"server-name.domain.com"}
```

Next I opened port 9300

I wrote a simple bash script to return some numbers

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
  -t|--to)
  COUNTTO=$2
  shift
  ;;
esac
shift
printf 'Count to %i\n' $COUNTTO

for COUNT in $(seq 1 $COUNTTO); do
  echo $COUNT
  sleep 0.1
done
```

I started up websocketd pointing to my bash script

```
/app/websocketd --port=9300 /app/count.sh --to 7
```

I opened Simple Web Socket Client in Chrome and connected

```
ws://server-name.domain.com:9300
```

Success! It returned the following.

```
Count to 7
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

**At this point I know websocketd works and logstash works. Now is when the trouble starts.**

Logstash websocket input configuration file

```
input {
  websocket {
    codec => "plain"
    url => "ws://127.0.0.1:9300/"
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash-log.txt"
  }
}
```

Run configtest

```
/app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/logstash agent --config /app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash.conf --configtest
```

Receive "Configuration OK"

Start up websocketd

```
/app/websocketd --port=9300 /app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/logstash agent --config /app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash.conf
```

Back in Simple Web Socket Client, I connect to ws://server-name.domain.com:9300. I see a message pop up that I started a session.

```
Tue, 05 Jul 2016 20:07:13 -0400 | ACCESS | session    | url:'http://server-name.domain.com:9300/' id:'1467732248361139010' remote:'192.168.0.1' command:'/app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/logstash' origin:'chrome-extension://pfdhoblngbopfeibdeiidpjgfnlcodoo' | CONNECT
```

I try to send "hello world". Nothing apparent happens on the server. After about 15 seconds I see a disconnect message in my console window. logstash-log.txt is never created.

Any ideas for what to try? Thank you!

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried putting the following in a bash script called "launch_logstash.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

exec /app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/logstash agent --config /app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash.conf
```

Then I started websocketd like so:

```
/app/websocketd --port=9300 /app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/launch_logstash.sh
```

Same result; no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading the websocketd documentation more closely, it sends the data received on the socket to a program's stdin. I was trying to listen to a socket in my logstash config, but the data is actually going to that app's stdin. I changed my config to this:

```
input {
  stdin { }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash-log.txt"
  }
}
```

Then launched websocketd like this:

```
/app/websocketd --port=9300 /app/logstash-2.3.3/bin/logstash agent --config /app/logstash-2.3.3/logstash.conf
```

So in short, until logstash-websocket-input implements their server option, stdin{} and stdout{} are the input and output if using websocketd as the web server.